# The printer couldn't print node print job

Tags: printing, electron

I'm using the "electron-printer" package to RAW print from my electron app. The document makes it to the printer quee but it goes to error and the system shows a "The printer couldn't print node print job" message. I'm attaching my code for reference.

```
var printer = require('electron-printer');

function printString(str){
    printer.printDirect({
        data: str,
        printer: printer.getDefaultPrinterName(),
        type: 'RAW', 
        success:function(jobID){
            console.log("Succesfully sent to printer. Job id is: "+jobID);
        }, 
        error:function(err){console.log(err);}
    });
}
```

Comment: Where do you see the error, is it output to the console? Is this the exact error message, as I'm unable to find anything on the web? It may also be helpful to know which OS you're on.

Comment: I'm using Windows (10). The error pops up where Windows 10 notifications usually come up (bottom right corner). The printer quee puts the document in a "Error-Printing" status. The console actually executes the function that's called on "success". I tried changing type to TEXT or any other combination of the RAW states that it supports, but the error is always the same.